# selenium scraper works, but after some time chrome says "This site can't be reached"

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scraping the US Patent website, their robot.txt has no restrictions when it comes to scraping, but after a few hundred requests, I get this isse:[image]

I clear cookies after each search request, and I also have tried using different proxies. Any ideas as to why this is happening? My code works fine, but after 10-20 minutes of scraping I get this error.

Here's my code but I don't think it will be very helpful at all as the code works fine til this point

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time
import pandas as pd
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
num_rows = 50000
df = pd.read_csv('company_names.csv').head(500)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=range(num_rows),columns=['company_name','link','patent title','abstract','company_id'])
row_number = 0
for company in df['company_name']:
    company_id = df.loc[df.company_name == company, 'company_id'].values[0]
    print(company_id)
    df_new.iloc[row_number,4]=str(company_id)
    print(company)
    df_new.iloc[row_number,0]=str(company)
    driver.get("http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/")
    driver.get("http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm")
    search_box = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/textarea")))
    print('found search box')
    search_box.send_keys("AN/"+'"'+str(company)+'"')
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]").click()
    #multiple results
        
    check_table = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]")))
    if check_table.text == 'PAT. NO.':
        #multiple links
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr")
        num_patents = len(rows)-1
        min_patents = min(10,num_patents)
        for row in range(min_patents):
            df_new.iloc[row_number,4]=str(company_id)
            df_new.iloc[row_number,0]=str(company)
            title_link = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr["+str(row+2)+"]/td[4]/a")))
            link = title_link.get_attribute('href')
            print(str(link))
            title_text = title_link.text
            print(title_text)
            df_new.iloc[row_number,1] = str(link)
            df_new.iloc[row_number,2] = str(title_text)
            title_link.click()
            abstract = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/p[1]")))
            print(abstract.text)
            df_new.iloc[row_number,3] = str(abstract.text)
            row_number += 1
            driver.back()
            #get patent abstract data

    elif check_table.text == 'Inventors:':
        #one link
        df_new.iloc[row_number,4]=str(company_id)
        df_new.iloc[row_number,0]=str(company)
        abstract = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/p[1]")))
        link = driver.current_url
        df_new.iloc[row_number,1] = str(link)
        abstract_text = abstract.text
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/font')
        title_text = title.text
        print(title_text)
        df_new.iloc[row_number,2] = str(title_text)
        print(abstract_text)
        df_new.iloc[row_number,3] = str(abstract_text)
        row_number += 1
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
    

df_new.to_csv('patent_results.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Terms of Use for USPTO websites](https://www.uspto.gov/terms-use-uspto-websites#heading-6):

> USPTO’s online databases are not designed or intended to be a source for bulk downloads of USPTO data when accessed through the website’s interfaces. Individuals, companies, IP addresses, or blocks of IP addresses who, in effect, deny or decrease service by generating unusually high numbers of database accesses (searches, pages, or hits), whether generated manually or in an automated fashion, may be denied access to USPTO servers without notice.

next paragraph:

> Bulk data products may be separately obtained from the USPTO, either for free or at the cost of dissemination. For details, see information on [Electronic Bulk Data Products](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/electronic-bulk-data-products).